# Can WCF accept JSON encoded using single quotes and non-quoted identifiers?

Tags: wcf, json

Is there a way that I can instruct WCF to accept JSON that is formatted using either single quotes (as opposed to double quotes):

```
{
   'foo': 'bar'
}
```

Or using non-quoted identifiers like so:

```
{
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

As it is, it seems like JSON will only be accepted if it is formatted like so:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Using either of the first two example results in a 400 (bad request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two examples are invalid JSON texts.
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

```
object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
end-object

member = string name-separator value

string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark

quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
```

Comment: That the first example is illegal does not help much when many JavaScript frameworks are using single quote around property name as fx https://github.com/request/request

Comment: @LarsLadegaard who cares about javascript?

Answer (score 2):

`DataContractJsonSerializer` always *writes* strict JSON.

At various points during deserialization (generally missing end tags for arrays or objects, or improper escaping, or improperly formatted numbers), it will *accept incorrect, non-strict JSON*.

However, I can tell you definitively that this is not one of those cases. `DataContractJsonSerializer` always requires double-quoted strings for JSON.

Hope this helps!