# WCF: Why do I keep getting a 400 Bad Request Error?

Tags: c#, wcf, json

I'm trying to invoke a WCF service method using POST and sending data encoded as json but no matter what I keep getting a bad request error.

This is my method signature:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public int Publish(List<MeasurementData> data)
```

This is my `MeasurementData` model definition:

```
[DataContract]
public class MeasurementData
{
   [DataMember]
   public string ReadingDate;

   [DataMember]
   public int Unit { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string ParameterAbbreviation { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public decimal Measurement { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it from the client:

```
var data = '[{"Measurement": 12678967.543233, "ParameterAbbreviation": "String content", "ReadingDate": "String content","Unit": 2147483647}]';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/SiennaAddMeasurement/Publish",
    data: "{ 'data' : '" + data + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
     }
});
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this below post.

[400 Bad Request HTTP Response using a WCF POST via JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146329/400-bad-request-http-response-using-a-wcf-post-via-jquery)

some one has already faced such an error it turned to be an error related to the parameters pass.

hope it can help